# Update large amount of data postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.4

I have two main tables: Account and Item. An account can have multiple items. That said, my item table has more than 4M records.

The thing is that I have an Account with more than 41k items, and I want to update the `deleted_at` column of its items to the actual timestamp, but my query doesn't finish. I receive an error saying that the query could not be finished due to a timeout.

This is the query I'm trying to run:

`UPDATE "Item" SET "deleted_at"='2015-12-23 19:10:00' WHERE account_id = 859;`

Even in smaller accounts, given the huge number of items stored in the database, the query takes so long to finish.

However, if I select all the account's item, the query finishes in nearly 3s, which, in my opinion, is acceptable. So, I'm imagining that the problem might be related with the `UPDATE` itself.

So, what can I do to be able to update those records?

Another problem that I'm facing right now is the growth of the item table (At this point, if I run `SELECT count(*) from "Item"`, I also get a timeout).

I need to know what can I do and how can I optimize the database in order to do that, and to deal with the raise in the number of records.

Thanks!

**Edit #1:**

I check pg_locks when updating running `SELECT relation::regclass, * FROM pg_locks WHERE NOT GRANTED;` and nothing was showed. So, I'm assuming that the query is not waiting for any lock.

I tried to run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM ...` both for Item and Account tables. The Item query in my live database don't ever finished (timed out again...), so I ran it in my local dump. These are the results I got.

```
Account - Remote database
---------------------------
"QUERY PLAN"
"Seq Scan on \"Account\"  (cost=0.00..532.45 rows=4245 width=539) (actual time=0.032..8.919 rows=4247 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=97 read=393 written=31"
"Planning time: 0.063 ms"
"Execution time: 12.849 ms"

Item - Local dump
---------------------------
"QUERY PLAN"
"Seq Scan on \"Item\"  (cost=0.00..869926.62 rows=19644062 width=233 (actual time=8.408..11660.646 rows=19492549 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=4171 read=669315"
"Planning time: 0.323 ms"
"Execution time: 14055.453 ms"
```

As you asked for, this is my tables structure:

**Account** (id, account_name, uID, cloud_id, created_at, updated_at, user_id, deleted_at)

**Account Indexes**: none

**Account Constraints**: id -> Primary key, user_id -> Foreign key, cloud_id -> Foreign Key

**Item** (id, name, is_favorite, last_modified, item_id, parent_id, item_size, item_type, read_only, mime_type, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at, cloud_item_id, account_id)

**Item Constraints**: id -> Primary key, account_id -> Foreign key, item_id -> Unique

**Item Indexes**: account_id, cloud_item_id, created_at, item_name, parent_id, item_id.

I created this indexes because these are the fields that I mostly use to search for an item. I don't know if this is part of the problem too.

All foreign keys of all tables have their `onUpdate` set to `CASCADE` and `onDelete` set to `SET NULL`.

Also, nothing is deleted from these two tables. If you delete an account, or an item, we set the `deleted_at` timestamp to the actual one.

**Tables size** (number or records): 
Account: 4.247, Item: 19.492.549 (yes, a lot more than I told you initially).

Another interesting fact is that if I import my live database, which is running in an Azure Virual Machine, into my machine, despite the fact that the query takes so long, it finishes. On the other hand, in the remote database I cannot even count the total number of items I have stored. My local machine has an SSD, the vm doesn't.

VM Specifications: 2 cores, 7 GB RAM, 1 data disk with max IOPS 500.

I'm using Postgres 9.4.

Please let me know if you need more information, I'd be glad to provide it to you.

Thank you!

Comment: That sounds as if you are waiting for locks, rather than the statement really taking so long. Check pg_locks to see if your update is waiting for something: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring  As far as the slow `select` is concerned, please read this: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions and provide the missing information (**edit** your question). Although unrelated, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers they are much more trouble than they are worth it.

Comment: Those volumes you were quoting (4 mil / 41k) about sound far from overwhelming...  Can you show the structures of your tables, specifically the constraints and indexes?

Comment: Thank you for your help guys! I've updated the post with the additional information you asked for @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @Hambone I've updated the post with the constraints, indexes and some other additional information. Thanks!